# Can't pass props to bottomTabNavigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to pass user information to createBottomTabNavigator and then set the title on ProfileStack as the name of the user

I tried passing through this.props.navigation.setParams(...) but i can't do that since the code for creating bottom tab navigator looks like this

```php
ProfileStack.navigationOptions = {
    tabBarLabel: () => {
        return null
    },
    tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => (
        <Image style={[...styles]}
               source={uri}/>
    ),
};

const tabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
    HomeStack,
    SearchStack,
    DashboardStack,
    ProfileStack,
});
```

```php
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, SafeAreaView, View, Text} from 'react-native';

export default class SettingsScreen extends Component {

    static navigationOptions = {
        title: 'Profil',
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <SafeAreaView>
                <Text>Profil</Text>
            </SafeAreaView>
        )
    }
}
```

I expect to change the title to something passed through props, 
like

```php
let name = this.props.navigation.props.getParam('user').name

static navigationOptions = {
    title: name
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot pass info to static navigationOptions like in your code, you can try instead to pass the new title setting a param in the navigation

```
static navigationOptions ({navigation}) => {
    return {
         title: navigation.state.params.title
    }
}

// when some events are triggered
this.props.navigation.setParams({title: "Example"});
```